# cursorPos.insertInlineImage() gives error: "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again"

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use a script contained within a Google document to load an image from a url and insert it at the cursor position, but inserting the image with `cursorPos.insertInlineImage(image)` gives the error `We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again`

Inserting the image with `getBody().appendImage(image)` or inserting text with `cursorPos.insertText("hello")` works fine.

```js
function onOpen(e) {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("Test")
    .addItem("Insert", "insertTest")
    .addToUi();
}

function insertTest() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?E%3Dmc%5E2").getBlob();
  var cursorPos = doc.getCursor();
  doc.getBody().appendImage(image); // works
  cursorPos.insertText("test!"); // works
  cursorPos.insertInlineImage(image); // gives error
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm happy to say found a simple workaround!

```js
function insertTest() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?E%3Dmc%5E2").getBlob();
  var cursorElement = doc.getCursor().getElement();
  body.insertImage(body.getChildIndex(cursorElement), image);
}
```

Unfortunately, if the cursor is inside a paragraph, this will throw an error saying cursorElement is not a child of body. The solution is to pass the upper-most level parent of cursorElement to getChildIndex.

```js
function insertTest() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?E%3Dmc%5E2").getBlob();
  var cursorElement = doc.getCursor().getElement();
  body.insertImage(body.getChildIndex(getTopLevelParent(cursorElement)), image);
}

// get the uppermost level parent of an element within a body section
function getTopLevelParent(element) {
  var parent = element.getParent();
  if (parent.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.BODY_SECTION) {
    return element;
  } else {
    return getTopLevelParent(parent);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly simpler workaround. 
The idea is to append the image to the end of the body of the document, then move it to the cursor position. 
In the process, whatever it was about the original codecogs image that prevented `insertInlineImage` from working before is expunged and everyone is happy!

```
function insertTest() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
              "http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?E%3Dmc%5E2")
              .getBlob();
  var cursorPos = doc.getCursor();
  var imageCopy = (image = body.appendImage(image)).copy();
      cursorPos.insertInlineImage(imageCopy);
      image.removeFromParent();
}
```